# Linux Cronjob does not execute

Tags: linux, bash, cron-task

I created a cronjob with the command crontab -e:

```
* * * * *   (filename).sh
```

This file test.sh should be executed every minute. But it doesn't work.

I know that it is not the script because i did run bash (name of the file) it works so the crontad is the issue.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @malik,  whats the entry in crontab?

Comment: sorry i am new crotnab what do mean by entry ?

Comment: Use `/path/to/file.sh`

Comment: See if this [server fault canonical question](https://serverfault.com/q/449651/30957) helps you.

Answer (score 0):

every minute:

```
* * * * * sciptname.sh
```

every 24hours (every midnight):

0 0  * * * sciptname.sh

Comment: @jww, will keep it in consideration.